# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have such test class:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.scalatest.{ConfigMap, BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}

class MyTrainingSuiteIT extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {

private[this] var _sc: SparkContext = null
private[this] val defaultCoresNumber = 1
private[this] val defaultMaster = s"local[$defaultCoresNumber]"
private[this] val defaultName = "some-spark-integration-test"

override def beforeAll(configMap: ConfigMap): Unit = {
  super.beforeAll()
  val mode = configMap.get("mode").get
  mode match {
    case "local" =>
       val coresNumber = configMap.get("cores").get
      _sc = new SparkContext(s"local[$coresNumber]", defaultName)
    case "docker" =>
       println("Docker was chosen")
      _sc = new SparkContext(defaultMaster, defaultName)
    case "cluster" =>
      val clusterType = configMap.get("clusterType").get
      println(s"Cluster of type [$clusterType] was chosen.")
      _sc = new SparkContext(defaultMaster, defaultName)
    case _ =>
      println("Unknow mode was chosen")
      _sc = new SparkContext(defaultMaster, defaultName)
  }
}

override def afterAll(): Unit = {
  _sc.stop()
  _sc = null
  super.afterAll()
}

test("Context testing") {
  assert(defaultMaster == s"local[$defaultCoresNumber]")
}

test("Fail test") {
  assert(3 === 2)
}

}
```

Firstly, I compile it in IntelliJ IDEA and then I try to perform it with such command in terminal:

```
scala -classpath /home/Downloads/scalatest_2.10.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R /home/hspark/datasource-tests.jar -s package.name.MyTrainingSuiteIT -Dmode=local -Dcores=2
```

And after I do ScalaTest's window is opened and I have such message:

Event: Run Aborted

Message:A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: org/apache/spark/SparkContext

Summary: Total number of tests run: 0

Suites: completed 0, aborted 0

Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you add the Spark lib to the classpath?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using a build tool such as SBT.

Comment: @PimVerkerk Should I do like this:
scala -classpath /home/Downloads/scalatest_2.10.jar,/home/spark/core-1.2.19.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R /home/hspark/datasource-tests.jar -s package.name.MyTrainingSuiteIT -Dmode=local -Dcores=2 ?

Comment: Use a ':' as separator like this `-classpath /home/Downloads/scalatest_2.10.jar:/home/spark/core-1.2.19.jar`.

Comment: @PimVerkerk thank you. It works!

Comment: @Oleksandr, can you compile all these comments into an answer?

Comment: @PimVerkerk and now I have another exception:
Message:
An exception or error caused a run to abort: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider. (java.lang.String, akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream, akka.actor.Scheduler, akka.actor.DynamicAccess)

Comment: This is nog enough information, could you open a new issue and include the stacktrace?

Comment: @PimVerkerk I created new isse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480854/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-in-scalatest
Please, take a look at this, may be you can help me again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working version of the scala command:

`scala -classpath /home/Downloads/scalatest_2.10.jar:/home/spark/core-1.2.19.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R /home/hspark/datasource-tests.jar -s package.name.MyTrainingSuiteIT -Dmode=local -Dcores=2`

The source of the exception was the missing spark lib on the classpath.
 As @Ben suggested a build tool such as SBT would make it easier to run your test.