# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException in scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have such test class:

```
package com.my.spark.test

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.scalatest.{ConfigMap, BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}

class MyTrainingSuiteIT extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  private[this] var _sc: SparkContext = null
  private[this] val defaultCoresNumber = 1
  private[this] val defaultMaster = s"local[$defaultCoresNumber]"
  private[this] val defaultName = "some-spark-integration-test"

  override def beforeAll(configMap: ConfigMap): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    val mode = configMap.get("mode").get
    mode match {
      case "local" =>
        val coresNumber = configMap.get("cores").get
        _sc = new SparkContext(s"local[$coresNumber]", defaultName)
      case "docker" =>
        println("Docker was chosen")
        _sc = new SparkContext(defaultMaster, defaultName)
      case "cluster" =>
        val clusterType = configMap.get("clusterType").get
        println(s"Cluster of type [$clusterType] was chosen.")
        _sc = new SparkContext(defaultMaster, defaultName)
      case _ =>
        println("Unknow mode was chosen")
        _sc = new SparkContext(defaultMaster, defaultName)
    }
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    _sc.stop()
    _sc = null
    super.afterAll()
  }

  test("Context testing") {
    assert(defaultMaster == s"local[$defaultCoresNumber]")
  }
}
```

And I try to perform test with commandline and scalatest(I need to do it without sbt or maven):

```
scala -classpath /home/huge/list/of/jars.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -R /home/hspark/my_spark_project/target/project-tests.jar -s com.my.spark.test.MyTrainingSuiteIT -Dmode=local -Dcores=2
```

After that ScalaTest window is opened and I see error:

```
Event: Run Aborted

Message: An exception or error caused a run to abort: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider. (java.lang.String, akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream, akka.actor.Scheduler, akka.actor.DynamicAccess) 
Summary: Total number of tests run: 0

Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0 
Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2902) 
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066)  
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:77) 
scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) 
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:74) 
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:85) 
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:85) scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) 
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:546) 
akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111) 
akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104) 
org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121) 
org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53) 
org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52) 
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1920) 
scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) 
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1911) 
org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55) 
org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:253) 
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:53) 
org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:254) 
org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194) 
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277) 
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:450) 
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:162) 
com.my.spark.test.MyTrainingSuiteIT.beforeAll(MyTrainingSuiteIT.scala:19) 
org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:253) 
com.my.spark.test.MyTrainingSuiteIT.run(MyTrainingSuiteIT.scala:6) 
org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55) 
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563) 
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) 
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557) 
org.scalatest.tools.RunnerJFrame$RunnerThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(RunnerJFrame.scala:1565) 
org.scalatest.tools.RunnerJFrame$RunnerThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(RunnerJFrame.scala:1563) 
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722) 
org.scalatest.tools.RunnerJFrame$RunnerThread.run(RunnerJFrame.scala:1563)
```

And the question is, what should I do to perform tests correctly? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there were several akka implementation in classpath. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685021/4054598